# Does a robotic lawn mower sense that it is outside the perimeter wire? If so, how?

Tags: sensor

I have a robotic lawn mower. Sometimes if the grass is really slippery, the lawn mower can slide outside of the perimeter wire. When that happens, the lawn mower shuts down and I get a notification on my phone. The notification says that the mower is outside of its wire.

1. Does the lawn mower really have sensors that can distinguish whether the movwer is inside or outside the perimeter? Or does it only assume that it is outside, since it has crossed the perimeter wire once (and only once)?
2. How does the lawn mower know that it is outside of the perimeter wire?

Comment: What if the mower simply **counts** the number of rotations of its wheels. That would work well enough if the wheels never slip. But what if the wheels do slip? Can the mower still determine where it is?

Comment: Welcome to the site. This site is for questions on electronics circuit design, rather than a home technology query like yours. Unfortunately, you've brought your question to the wrong place. Good luck getting your answer elsewhere, though.

Comment: Possibly useful search term "induction loop transmitter"

Comment: @TonyM could you please clarify your comment here? I would think that a question on how a boundary wire for a robotic lawn mower works is within scope of the site. The "About" page states to "build a library of detailed answers to every question about electronics design. I came here to find techniques on how to find faults in this design, isn't that relevant?

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye, because the question is subjective and its answers may well be speculative. The accepted answer is indeed speculative ('tentative') and broad and is refuted by a detailed comment. It is not your "detailed answer...about electronics design" that fully resolves the question. No other answers or any discussions have been attracted in seven months.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment into a tentative answer.

There is a low power radio transmission system called the "inductive loop" which uses a large loop of wire as an antenna. It provides good signal strength within the loop, and virtually none outside.

This allows induction loops to provide radio coverage e.g. within a building such as a concert hall or theatre or hospital with virtually no interference to other spectrum users outside the building. One common use is to help hearing aid users at the theatre.

But its characteristics are just about ideal for confining a robot within a space defined by a perimeter wire. Transmit a simple code at low power. If the robot loses the signal, it must stop. Simple as that.

Now I don't know if any specific lawnmower uses this system, but it's the most obvious candidate.

Comment: I haven't taken my lawnmower apart yet but I think it works differently. From my observations it looks as if the lawnmower can only sense the boundary wire at very close distance. But the emitted electro-magnetic signal is directional. So it can sense if it is standing inside or outside of the loop. Look at the instructions for preparing your green: you can also create islands within the green that should be excluded for mowing.